# Elif this examples from Rauschmayer's textbook

Tags: javascript, regex

So, Rauschmayer did a great job teaching JS, but I cannot wrap my mind around these two little baddies:

```
function insertName(str, name) {
    return str.replace(
        /NAME/g,
        function (completeMatch, offset) {
            if (offset === 0 ||
                (offset > 0 && str[offset-1] !== '"')) {
                return name;
            } else {
                return completeMatch;
            }
        }
    );
}

function insertName(str, name) {
    var tmpPrefix = ' ';
    str = tmpPrefix + str;
    str = str.replace(
        /([^"])NAME/g,
        function (completeMatch, prefix) {
            return prefix + name;
        }
    );
    return str.slice(tmpPrefix.length); // remove tmpPrefix
}
```

Can somebody explain me how he passes offset parameter in first example, and what is happening with it?
What does prefix parameter in second example, where it comes from?

Comment: He doesn't *pass* `offset`, he just defines the optional argument `offset` - check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Answer (score 0):

The `offset` is a parameter that is passed by the `replace` method to the `replacement` function, when one is used. (*See [Specifying  _function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) for the parameters of the **replacement** function*). It specifies the index, in the string, where the current match occurred.

Try

```js
'abcada'.replace(/a/g, (match,offset)=>console.log(`match="${match}", offset=${offset}`))
```

In the second example the regular expression includes a capturing group, so these (*this in the specific case*) are also added as parameters right after the `completeMatch`.

In the example code the prefix corresponds to the capturing group that is right before the NAME and so it is named prefix (*it captures any single-character except `"`*)

Answer (score 0):

`String,prototype.replace()` can have a function as second parameter, while the first parameter is a regular expression or a string. Let's call this function A.
The first parameter of A is always the whole matched substring. The second (third, fourth, …) parameter may be the matched capture groups of the regular expression. If no capture groups are defined, this parameter is the offset, which means the index of the match inside the original string. (See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter))

In the first example the RegEx is `/NAME/g` which HAS NO capture group, and in the second example the RegEx is `/([^"])NAME/g` which HAS a capture group (defined by the parentheses `(` and `)`).